# Get list of channels a user is a member of

Tags: slack, slack-api

Writing a slack bot and I would like to be able to get a list of all the channels my bot is a member of. One way to do this is to call `https://slack.com/api/channels.list`, get a (potentially large) list of all channels and then search for the channels that the current (bot) user is a member of. This works fine, but seems very heavy handed.

Is there a better way? To get just the channels that a given user is a member of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no shorter way to get this information.

Actually, Slack recommends to use the new `conversations` methods for this task, since the `members` property in all other methods, e.g. channels.list has recently been changed to only return a truncated user list. See [here](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-10-members-array-truncating) for details.

With `conversations` you have to make an additional call per channel to get all channels a user is a member of. However it will work with all types of channels (e.g. public channels, private channels) at the same time.

The basic approach is:

1. Get the list of all conversations from [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)
2. Get the list of members per conversation form [`conversations.members`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members).

So if you want your Slack app to be future proof and also work with large number of users better use the `conversations` methods for your task.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Especially the heads up on members being truncated and eventually removed. This is an internal bot so it's not exactly a massive problem, but it's still a little odd that I can't just get a list of channels for a user.

Comment: I agree, but there doesn't seam to be any other way. Naturally, you would expect it to be part of [users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info), but its not. Think I will send Slack a mail to ask for this feature. Especially with the new conversations methods you need way too many calls to get that info.

Answer (score 13):

I think [`users.conversations`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations) is what you're looking for. Without additional params it will return all public channels the calling user is a member of.

Comment: This new endpoint has been introduced in April 2018 and is making the job def. much easier.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can now list user channels/conversations using:

https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations